# Mac office, outlook keep calendar invite in e-mail box

Tags: ms-office

When I recieve an calendar invite and send an 'accept' the message itself is being deleted out of my mail box. I know the invite itself is able to stay in your mailbox but the big question is how?!

Does anyone know how to keep your outlook calendar invite as an e-mail?

Answer (score 3):

It's simple (until MS changes the pref on this): just accept the invitation to the meeting ***from the calendar***, NOT your inbox.

Answer (score 1):

As [noted on the official microsoft forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macoutlook/id-like-to-accept-meeting-request-and-keep-still/d66058c0-4567-423e-b6a0-a5cd8c174f16?auth=1) it's not a feature on outlook for mac. This feature is only available at the Windows versions of outlook and never been a feature of the mac version.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, my work allowed us to connect to Exchange via Mac. I have used, for years BusyMac's BusyCal because it has far superior Alert window options (that just matters a lot to me.) I put my account creds into BusyCal and have been getting sync perfectly. Today, not sure why, I wondered what would happen if I accepted a meeting from BusyCal instead of Outlook.

Answer: It keeps the invitation in the Inbox! (Something I have wanted so much, too).

Up to you if having that matters enough to buy BusyCal. But at least we have a solution until MS build it into Outlook for Mac.